# dual diamond structure using nested repetition structures in python 3

Tags: python

I am working on improving my skills in python and I am stumped with one part of the course material. We were given the challenge to create a program that asks the user for half of the size of a "diamond" and prints the attached image, two diamonds with a single space in between them. I was able to get a single diamond but cannot figure out how to print two, can someone help out, attached is my code.

[image: two diamond pic]

```
def Diamond(rows): 
    n = 0
    for i in range(1, rows + 1): 

        # loop to print spaces 
        for j in range (1, (rows - i) + 1): 
            print(end = " ") 

        # loop to print star 
        while n != (2 * i - 1): 
            print("*", end = "") 
            n = n + 1
        n = 0

        # line break 
        print()  

    k = 1
    n = 1
    for i in range(1, rows): 
        # loop to print spaces 
        for j in range (1, k + 1): 
            print(end = " ") 
        k = k + 1

        # loop to print star 
        while n <= (2 * (rows - i) - 1): 
            print("*", end = "") 
            n = n + 1
        n = 1

        #line break
        print()




# number of rows input 
rows = int(input("Please enter the size of half of a diamond: "))
Diamond(rows)
```

Comment: can  you add some kind of desired output and current output?

Comment: every line of diamond you have to keep on list (instead of printing) and later display every line from list two times (before you draw next line). OR you have to change code in current function and it has to draw every element two times. You can't do this using current function without changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd keep it simple and just **duplicate** the row you've just generated to create the 2nd diamond:

```py
def generateRow(rowIdx, maxNumOfAsterisks):
    expectedAsterisks = 1 + 2 * rowIdx
    halfNumOfSpaces = int((maxNumOfAsterisks - expectedAsterisks) / 2)

    rowString = ""
    rowString += (" " * halfNumOfSpaces)
    rowString += ("*" * expectedAsterisks)
    rowString += (" " * halfNumOfSpaces)
    rowString += " " + rowString # Append the same row to generate the 2nd diamond
    return rowString


def printDiamond(halfSize):
    maxNumOfAsterisks = 1 + 2 * (halfSize - 1)
    for rowIdx in range(halfSize):
        print(generateRow(rowIdx, maxNumOfAsterisks))

    for rowIdx in range(halfSize-1, -1, -1):
        print(generateRow(rowIdx, maxNumOfAsterisks))


printDiamond(5)
```

Sample output would be:

```
    *         *    
   ***       ***   
  *****     *****  
 *******   ******* 
********* *********
********* *********
 *******   ******* 
  *****     *****  
   ***       ***   
    *         *
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easier if you break it down into functions that return stuff instead of printing directly. That way you can build on the single diamond data structure and manipulate it. The following uses very basic generator functions and makes use of [`str.center`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.center):

```
def updown(n):
    yield from range(1, n)
    yield from range(n, 0, -1)

def diamond(n):
    for i in updown(n):
        yield ('*' * (2*i - 1)).center(2*n - 1)

def diamonds(n, m):
    for lines in zip(*(diamond(n) for _ in range(m))):
        yield ''.join(lines)

>>> print('\n'.join(diamonds(5, 3)))
    *        *        *    
   ***      ***      ***   
  *****    *****    *****  
 *******  *******  ******* 
***************************
 *******  *******  ******* 
  *****    *****    *****  
   ***      ***      ***   
    *        *        *    
>>> print('\n'.join(diamonds(6, 2)))
     *          *     
    ***        ***    
   *****      *****   
  *******    *******  
 *********  ********* 
**********************
 *********  ********* 
  *******    *******  
   *****      *****   
    ***        ***    
     *          *
```

Answer (score 0):

Method that uses recursion:

```
def diamond(rows, whole_length=None):
    n = 2*rows - 1

    if whole_length is None:
        whole_length = n

    if rows < 1:
        return

    print('{:^{l}}'.format('*' * (whole_length+1-n), l=whole_length), end=' ')
    print('{:^{l}}'.format('*' * (whole_length+1-n), l=whole_length))
    diamond(rows - 1, whole_length)
    print('{:^{l}}'.format('*' * (whole_length+1-n), l=whole_length), end=' ')
    print('{:^{l}}'.format('*' * (whole_length+1-n), l=whole_length))


diamond(5)
```

Prints:

```
    *         *    
   ***       ***   
  *****     *****  
 *******   ******* 
********* *********
********* *********
 *******   ******* 
  *****     *****  
   ***       ***   
    *         *
```